# How to fix buttons shown as stairs

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For my internship I need to work with Wordpress. All good and well, but my custom html and css isn't shown properly and I can't seem to find the problem.

I've been puzzeling around a bit and the weird thing is my code shows correctly on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jduwrz4/) but it [doesn't on the website.](https://pasteboard.co/IygCf2S.png)

```css
.btn-group button {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 190px;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
}

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#zonnepanelen {
  background-color: #189538;
  border: 1px solid #189538;
  color: white;
  width: 33%;
  height: 80px;
}

#dakbekleden {
  background-color: #ff990a;
  border: 1px solid #ff990a;
  color: white;
  width: 33%;
  height: 80px;
}

#asbest {
  background-color: #0a5cff;
  border: 1px solid #0a5cff;
  color: white;
  width: 33%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="zonnepanelen"><b>Zonnepanelen</b> laten zetten?</button>
  <button id="dakbekleden">Een <b>dak</b> laten <b> bekleden</b>?</button>
  <button id="asbest"><b>Asbest</b> laten <b> verwijderen</b>?</button>
</div>
```

Like I said, I want the buttons to be in a row but I have no idea what I can try anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: Inspect to see if there any other style override your css, and maybe try to use `flex`

Comment: A mere _screenshot_ of the website where it doesn’t work is not helpful in solving this, impossible for anyone to figure out what the differences between that and your working jsfiddle version are. Reducing what you have on the website to a [mre] would be your responsibility here; in cases where you absolutely can’t manage to produce such a reduced example, you’d have to at least show us the actual live version.

Comment: @04FS I've added the site. I'm sorry I didn't give a live example.

Comment: @RobinKok You have a `<br>` between each button. Use your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Is that HTML code not written in a template file, but entered dynamically as part of the post content? Then Wordpress is probably adding the `<br>` to the line breaks, in that case a simple solution could be to write the code without line breaks then.

Comment: I wrote it without the <br> tag. Wordpress added that itself. I'm using a template, but I also added a custom html element and added the css to the custom css section. I thought that would work. First time Wordpress user, so I I'm a bit new to how Wordpress deals with things.

But the solution below helped me get the buttons right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox for this. Your problem most likely comes from using floats and not having the correct width for any of the elements.

I also removed the border styling on your buttons so all you have to do is just set the correct color for your buttons.

```css
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-group button {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  min-width: 190px;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  border: none;
}


#zonnepanelen {
  background-color: #189538;
}

#dakbekleden {
  background-color: #ff990a;
}

#asbest {
  background-color: #0a5cff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="zonnepanelen"><b>Zonnepanelen</b> laten zetten?</button>
  <button id="dakbekleden">Een <b>dak</b> laten <b> bekleden</b>?</button>
  <button id="asbest"><b>Asbest</b> laten <b> verwijderen</b>?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked!
I'll remember to use flex from now on.